# Setup a DKIM Recordset at Designate Service

Tags: dns-zone, openstack

I am trying to setup a DKIM record set at my working Openstack Designated Services, but because the TXT recordset is too big it must be done in section and I was not able to do that.

```
# openstack recordset create --type TXT --record "\"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=adfsdfdasfadsfasdfadsfadsfasdfdasffdasfadafdsfdzig2yAU1eszFpVdgxZEW6hD9gECcLxqsz+VUt4+6GdoLwtPfPtYZiYY25Rhx5wr3z3Z6bBhqfNfrqPNj8YH0WtU+5U9mV0Ou5tjGktePykqd/W6WlB8/EkLpVZon6kWnCLCwNy3Ad0PpquMviTimqUUQWF/zk9Q8KV40gZWkqeU29cTU1mZK8SdGrmDZrdhkQEA\" \"iVyzXCry841a5tlRDuQwcAvEVIxal9dNXN4lsCOj3cCVSJOkhfgsfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsgsdgDBU805LMGdg8dlHNqVm883wbZLOuS73IzlC+dq7hW0pbTScY61SABC9qxlRB14Sd3FQIDAQAB\"" XXXXXXXXXxX-d50b-4f4f-bf36-53cf23345b25 0A98446E-9755-11EE-BDE5-8E9233BD404C._domainkey.mydomain.com.
```

I got the error: `Provided object is not valid. Got a InvalidObject error with message Quotation marks should be escaped with backslash.`

So I change it use single quotes

```
# openstack recordset create --type TXT --record '"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=adfsdfdasfadsfasdfadsfadsfasdfdasffdasfadafdsfdzig2yAU1eszFpVdgxZEW6hD9gECcLxqsz+VUt4+6GdoLwtPfPtYZiYY25Rhx5wr3z3Z6bBhqfNfrqPNj8YH0WtU+5U9mV0Ou5tjGktePykqd/W6WlB8/EkLpVZon6kWnCLCwNy3Ad0PpquMviTimqUUQWF/zk9Q8KV40gZWkqeU29cTU1mZK8SdGrmDZrdhkQEA\" \"iVyzXCry841a5tlRDuQwcAvEVIxal9dNXN4lsCOj3cCVSJOkhfgsfgsdgsdgsdgsdgsgsdgDBU805LMGdg8dlHNqVm883wbZLOuS73IzlC+dq7hW0pbTScY61SABC9qxlRB14Sd3FQIDAQAB"' XXXXXXXXXxX-d50b-4f4f-bf36-53cf23345b25 0A98446E-9755-11EE-BDE5-8E9233BD404C._domainkey.mydomain.com.
```

The new error is: `Provided object is not valid. Got a InvalidObject error with message Empty spaces are not allowed in TXT record, unless wrapped in double quotes.`

When I try to use Horizon Dashboard the invert the chain as it want to whatever the order that I set on it.

Can someone help me with that setup? Is there any way to setup DKIM TXT record at Openstack Designated Services?